# Is it possible to place two buttons on left side of navigation bar with transformation of most left button on OnClick?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, navigation-drawer, uinavigationitem

I want to display two buttons or can say two images on left side of navigation bar with same TouchUpInSide method.
When I click on that two buttons the left most button should transform more to left and when i again click on the two buttons the left most button come back to original position.
Or another way:
I can place two UIImageView on left side of navigation bat and place one button with clear background and give event on that.

So is it possible and How?

Comment: use multiple Barbutton in programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add just simple UIButtons you can use the following method.

1) Create multiple UIButton objects

2) Add all those buttons to a UIView object

3) Create UIBarButtonItem and pass the UIView as a custom view

Code is as follows:

```
// create the container view
UIView* viewContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];

// Create buttons and add it to the container view
UIButton* btnAdd = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[btnAdd setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[viewContainer addSubview:btnAdd];

UIButton* btnRefresh = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[btnRefresh setTitle:@"Refresh" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[viewContainer addSubview:btnRefresh];

// now create a Bar button item with custom view
UIBarButtonItem* barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:viewContainer];

// Set the navigation bar's right button item
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barBtnItem;
```

or else if you want to add bar UIBarButtonItems go with adding multiple barbuttons as Anbu.Karthik said.

Here is the code to add multiple bar buttons items.

```
// Create UIToolbar to add two buttons in the right
UIToolbar* toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 44.01)];

// Create standard "add" button
UIBarButtonItem* btnAdd = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:NULL];
btnAdd.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

// Create spacer
UIBarButtonItem* spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];

// create standard "refresh" button
UIBarButtonItem* btnRefresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(btnRefresh_Clicked:)];
btnRefresh.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

// stick the buttons in the UIToolbar
[toolBar setItems:@[btnAdd, spacer, btnRefresh] animated:NO];

// Put the toolbar in the UINavigationBar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolBar];
```

Hope this will help you. :)